# Using a select box to obtain an id which will be use to add as foreign key id

Tags: php, mysql

I am busy programming my admin page.  In my one page i am using a select box where the administrator will first select the hub for which they want to add an area to and then secondly add the area.  When the administrator submit the form the info will be inserted into mysql table which have the following columns - id, name, fk_hub_id & active.

I have never worked with foreign keys and this is very new to me as i am also a beginner programmer.  Here is my code so far:

```
  <?php
// Start the session
    require_once('startsession.php');
    require_once('connectvars.php');
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Area</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    require_once('header.php');
    include('menu.php');

    // Write out our query.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hub";
    // Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $dropdown = "Select the Hub for which you want to insert an area: <select name='hub'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
    echo $dropdown;

?>
<form method="post" align= "right">
<table >
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Area:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" align= "right"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" align= "right" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      

    // Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
                    $hub_name = $_GET['id'];
                    $name=trim($_POST['name']) ;
                    $active=trim($_POST['active']);
                    $mistakes = array();

    if (empty($name) || (!(ctype_alpha($name)))) {
    $mistakes[] = 'ERROR - Your title is either empty or should only contain ALPHABET CHARACTERS.';
    }
    else
    {
    // accept title and sanitize it
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    }

    if (sizeof($mistakes) > 0) {

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($mistakes as $errors)
    {
    echo "<li>$errors</li>";
    //echo "<a href='areatitle_index.php'>Back...</a>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo '<br />';
    }
    else {
        $sql ="INSERT INTO `area`(name) VALUES ('$name')"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if($result) {
        //echo "<a href='menu.php'>Back to main menu</a>";
        //echo "<BR>";
        }
        else{
        echo "ERROR - The same Title already exist in the database";
            }
            }
            }
?>
</form>

<table class="table2" >
<br>
<tr>
    <th> ID </th>
    <th> Area </th>
    <th> Active </th>
    <th colspan = '1' >  </th>
    </tr>

            <?php

            // Connect to the database
            $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM area ");

            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $id = $test['id'];  
                echo "<tr align='center'>"; 
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['id']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['name']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['active']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='area_view.php?id=$id'>Edit</a>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
            // close connection 
            mysql_close();
            ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope i am on the right track.  My question is - How do i get the id from my select box option as the value for my fk_hub_id?  I know i still need to change my insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Include your dropdown element into your form and recieve its value in `$_POST['hub']` variable.

```
<?php      
    $dropdown = "<select name='hub'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

?>

<form method="post" align= "right">
<table >
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Area:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" align= "right"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Select the Hub for which you want to insert an area: </td>
       <td><?php echo $dropdown; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" align= "right" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Is this <td><?= $dropdown; ?></td> right?   my dropdown list has disappeared.

Comment: @Alwina yes, `<?= ` is just shortcut for `<? echo`. May be your settings don't allow you to use `<?` shorcuts. I have edited a code.

Comment: Can you maybe help me with the insert statement?

Comment: @Alwina I think you missed space character. Use $sql ="INSERT INTO `area` (name) VALUES ('$name')"; instead of $sql ="INSERT INTO `area`(name) VALUES ('$name')";.

Comment: Must I then do a separate update statement for the foreign key?